# Something wrong about Hashmap. But I can't replaced

Tags: android, sqlite, hashmap, crud

Please help me. Now i try to get database from SQlite, 
It is something wrong. But I can't fix

```css
"Explicit type argument HashMap<String, String> can be replaced with <> This inspection reports all new expressions with type arguments which can be replaced with diamond type <> Such <> syntax is not supported under Java 1.6 or earlier JVMs."
```

[This is my picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESE4l.png)

[And second picture on logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzJZy.png)

Comment: Is your execution environment set with Java 1.6??? If so, Set jdk 1.7 or above

Comment: As I can see it's not an error, it's just a warning??

Comment: Yes it just a warning. But when i click to show button.
The app will show message "๊Unfortunately,Myproject has stop".

I has second picture to show logcat.
Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: @Jorge How to set jdk 1.7.
This is code. T make follow old old my friend project.

Comment: If you open Project Structure-->SKD Location.... You can specify the path of the jdk you want to use. Check if it's 6 , and so, download jdk 7 or 8 and set the correct path

Comment: @Jorge I coding follow this link [Please click](http://www.thaicreate.com/mobile/android-sqlite-show-read.html)